# `transformIgnorePatterns` not working to include some node_modules

Tags: jestjs

I have the following config for Jest, which I was expecting to transform modules `foo` and `bar` inside node_modules, but ignore the rest:

```json
{
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules/(?!(foo)/)",
    "node_modules/(?!(bar)/)"
  ]
}
```

But it seems like neither are being transformed. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies hidden in [the documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transformignorepatterns-arraystring) (emphasis mine):

> If the file path matches **any** of the patterns, it will not be transformed.

The regex above creates a combination where any folder under node_modules will either match in the first pattern or the second pattern. Here's a visualization of the regex:

[image]

If the goal is to *not* match against certain libraries in node_modules, this combination of regex patterns make that impossible.

The solution is to combine them into a single statement:

```json
{
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules/(?!(foo|bar)/)"
  ]
}
```